# ASP.NET VB Compare 3 Date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

In my ASP.Net (VB Code) that I had 3 variable to store 3 different date.

how can I compare 3 variable to find the last day between 3 date ?

e.g.

```
date1 = '21/01/2011'

date2 = '31/12/2011'

date3 = '19/09/2011'
```

the result should be '31/12/2011' after comparsion

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just compare them:

```
Dim date1 As DateTime = #01/21/2011#
Dim date2 As DateTime = #12/31/2011#
Dim date3 As DateTime = #09/19/2011#

Dim last as DateTime = date1
If date2 > last Then
  last = date2
End If
If date3 > last Then
  last = date3
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work, with Linq library

```
Dim t1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("12/4/2011")
Dim t2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("12/2/2011")
Dim t3 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("12/3/2011")

Dim dates As New List(Of DateTime)()
dates.Add(t1)
dates.Add(t2)
dates.Add(t3)

Dim latestdate As DateTime = dates.Max()
```

When you put it in a list you don't need worry if you have 3 dates or 300. This will always work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method.